# How do I setup an Epson XP-446 printer to work with Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: printing

I got a new Epson printer, but it doesn’t have drivers to setup in Ubuntu.  I don’t know where to start. Used a USB cable to connect, the printer also has wifi.  When I added the printer in settings.  Three printer icons came up, but none of them work when I try to print a B&W pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I shortly search-engined for that model and found "works with your iPad". Then I stopped reading and concluded that it must be AirPrint-enabled and support IPP.

Which in turn means:

1. You should connect it to your WiFi.
2. Run the *`ippfind`* command.
3. See which "device URI" that command returns for you.
   **Example:** in my network I see `ipp://HPA0B3CCF051B9.local:631/ipp/printer` returned for a HP printer.
4. Run this command in your terminal, using the device URI for your Epson:

   ```
   sudo lpadmin -p epson -v <the-device-URI-returned-by-ippfind> -E -m everywhere
   ```

This should install a print queue named 'epson' and using an auto-generated PPD that takes into account all the responses which the printer returned on an automatically run *`Get-Printer-Attributes`* IPP query.